# Scanf a number with 300 digits in C

Tags: c, loops, sum, c-strings, digits

There is a question: I should scan a number with 300 digits and print the sum the digits but I cant scan it with `long long int` and I dont know what to do.

Comment: Read it to a `char*` and sum the digits manually

Comment: Hint: scan it in as a string and parse then each digit

Comment: If all you care about is the base-10 digits, then you don't really need or want to store a number.

Comment: This *would* have been a good learning exercise.  Unfortunately several "helpful" posters have now give you fully worked out answers, so you've missed out on the "aha" moment of seeing your way to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can *scan* the number as a string with `fgets()` or simply read one byte at a time with `getchar()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    int sum = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            sum += c - '0';
        else
            break;
    }
    printf("sum: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I you must use `scanf()`, here is an alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[2];
    int sum = 0;
    while (scanf("%1[0-9]", buf) == 1) {
        sum += *buf - '0';
    }
    printf("sum: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char digit;
    int sum = 0;
    while ( scanf("%c", &digit) != EOF) 
    {
         sum += digit - '0';
    }
    printf("sum: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The result will be incorrect as all input bytes will be handled including non digits, esp the newline.

Comment: as per the question, input will be digits only. So, this solution works.

Comment: The question is unclear as to how the input is retrieved from the user, but it is very complicated to ensure only digits can be read from the user via `scanf()` as posted. Even if the user only enters digits, the enter key typed to trigger the input will be returned by `scanf()` as a `'\n'` byte that will corrupt the sum.

Comment: While this might technically work by a very strict interpretation of the specification, most ways of inputting text via stdin will result in a trailing newline unless you specifically go out of your way to omit it, so I would consider this at the very least very fragile. (edit: Although TBH I never use `scanf` directly, so I don't actually recall whether `%c` scans newlines.)

Comment: @Arkku: `scanf("%c", &digit)` will indeed return 1 at end of line and set `digit` to `'\n'`, so `sum` will be updated incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case you need to enter a number as a string.

To enter a number you should use  the standard function `fgets`. The corresponding character array must have 302 characters: 300 characters for digits, one character for the new line character `'\n'` that is appended by the function `fgets` to the entered string and one character for the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string.

If the new line character `'\n'` is not present in the string it means that the user entered more than 300 characters.

Also the user can enter a number with leading or trailing spaces.

You need to check that the entered string contains a valid number.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int is_valid_number( const char *number )
{
    while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*number ) ) ++number;
    
    int valid = *number != '\0';
    
    if ( valid )
    {
        while ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )*number ) ) ++number;
        while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*number ) ) ++number;
        valid = *number == '\0';
    }       
    
    return valid;
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 300 };
    char number[N + 2] = { 0 };

    printf( "Enter a non-negative number (no greater than %d digits): ", N );

    fgets( number, sizeof( number ), stdin );
    
    int valid = strchr( number, '\n' ) != NULL;
    
    char *p = number;

    if ( valid )
    {
        number[ strcspn( number, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
        while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
        valid = is_valid_number( p );
    }
    
    if ( !valid )
    {
        puts( "Invalid number." );
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int sum = 0;

        for ( char *digit = p; isdigit( ( unsigned char )*digit ); ++digit )
        {
            sum += *digit - '0';
        }

        printf( "The sum of digits = %u\n", sum );
    }
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (no greater than 300 digits): 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
The sum of digits = 180
```

Comment: @chqrlie I  have changed the condition in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward solution seems to be to repeatedly read in 1-digit ints and sum them up while that works.
One digit numbers can easily be read into an int (no long needed) and even the sum of 300 digits will not exceed an int.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int digit=0;
    int sum=0;
    while(1==scanf("%1d",&digit))sum+=digit;
    printf("sum:%d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

This admittedly (thanks chqrlie for pointing out) expect an end of line, as it comes with e.g. test input at online compilers or judges. In an interactive prompt

> ... a single line of digit will not suffice, an explicit end of file with ^D is needed.

Comment: There is a small issue: your program will keep reading from stdin until end of file or a non number is entered. newlines and other whitespace will be ignored by the `%1d` format. Entering a single line of digit will not suffice, an explicit end of file with ^D is needed.

Comment: @chqrlie Why do you think that reading until EOF is not OK? I does not contradict the question. But I see what you mean, some obvious use cases are not covered. Let's see whether I can think of something....

Comment: Could not think of anything without ending up with the solution from one of the other answers. So I explicitly point out the specialty of this solution.@chqrlie

Answer (score -1):

you can use char to scan each digit. also in this way you do not need string.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nny7x.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer], and [please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: The ratio of code to explanation might prevent you from posting that code with that little explanation. But that just means that you have to add more prose explanation.